# Querying data from redshift table, column of data type timestamp

Tags: amazon-redshift, psql

I have a table 'abc' in redshift which has column 'xyz' of type timestamp. I am doing following query on it

> select * from abc where xyz = '2018-01-01 02:10:12';

Now the problem is I can see row with that 'xyz' value in the table. I do not know why if I change the equality sign to '>=' or '<=' it fetch's data but for the equality sign '=' it is not working.

Comment: I wonder if it is because the timestamp has a greater resolution than just seconds? For example, it might go down to miliseconds. Try `SELET xyz::text FROM abc` to convert the timestamp into raw text to see the actual contents.

Comment: Thanks, it was the issue.